# why doesn't `findAll(text="City:")` find the relevant string in Python using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code:

```
zipCode = str(11021)
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
main_body = soup.findAll(text="City:")
print main_body
```

to find the following html snippet:

```
<b>City:</b>
 <a href="/city/New-York-New-York.html">New York, NY</a>
```

when I use `"City:` I get `[]`.

when I use `"City"` I get `[u'City', u'City']`; but neither of this is the string i'm looking for.

Why doesn't `"City:"` work?  Is there something about the `:` that causes a problem?

Comment: Where do *you* see `<b>City:</b>` in that HTML source? I don't even see a link to `/city/New-York-New-York.html`.

Comment: I do see a `<b>Cities:</b>` with links following, is that what you were looking for instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters haha... hadn't even noticed there was a valid accessible URL included so hadn't looked at the page... I completely agree it helps if what you're looking for is the right thing though :)

Comment: Ah, for http://www.city-data.com/zips/10001.html there *is* the text `City:`. So the text varies by page, you need to account for that.

Comment: I cant find a zip code where `City:` doesn't come up.

Comment: Here's a zip code where `City:` doesn't come up: http://www.city-data.com/zips/11021.html. `Cities:`, plural, appears, but not `City:`

Answer (score 1):

You could change your approach and go for looking for anchors with `href`s pointing to `/city/`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.city-data.com/zips/11021.html').text)
for anchor in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'/city/')):
    print anchor.string

#Great Neck Estates, NY
#Thomaston, NY
#Great Neck Plaza, NY
#Kensington, NY
#University Gardens, NY
# etc...
```

And for 10001.html, it returns:

```
New York, NY
```

Answer (score 0):

here's code that works for me:

```
zipCode = str("07928")
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
if soup.findAll(text="City:") ==[]:
    cityNeeded = soup.findAll(text="Cities:")
    for t in cityNeeded:
        print t.find_next('a').string
else:
    cityNeeded = soup.findAll(text="City:")
    for t in cityNeeded:
        print t.find_next('a').string
```

Comment: If you're going down that route, why not: `soup.findAll(text=re.compile('(Cities|City):')` ?

Comment: I didn't even know that was an option.  Looks sharp!